# Adding leading zeros inbetween mixed strings

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
x <- c("MB1",  "MB11" ,"MB12" ,"MB13", "B1",  "B11", "B12", "B13", "B2")
```

and would like it to convert to

```
x
[1]"MB01"  "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11" "B12" "B13" "B02"
```

x only contains either "MB" or "B" as leading string, followed by maximum two digits.

i know how to str_pad, so i would like to perform something like

```
new.vector < paste0("Any Letter you find in each element of x", str_pad("numerical elements of x", 2, pad="0"))
```

or any other way, which can achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `str_extract(x, "[A-Z]+")` for "Any letter you find in each element of x" and `str_extract(x, "[0-9]+")` for "numerical elements of x" and I think you code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) gsub** Remove the digits and non-digits respectively and combine back using sprintf.  No packages are used.

```
sprintf("%s%02d", gsub("\\d", "", x), as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", x)))
## [1] "MB01" "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11"  "B12"  "B13"  "B02"
```

**2) trimws** This variation using trimws also uses only base R.

```
sprintf("%s%02d", trimws(x,, "\\d"), as.numeric(trimws(x,, "\\D")))
## [1] "MB01" "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11"  "B12"  "B13"  "B02"
```

**3) gsubfn** An ever shorter solution involves extracting the digits, converting to numeric, padding and then inserting back in using gsubfn.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\d+", ~ sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(digits)), x)
## [1] "MB01" "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11"  "B12"  "B13"  "B02"
```

**4) sub** Shorter yet we can use only sub by looking for one digit suffixes and inserting a zero.  No packages are used.

```
sub("(\\D)(\\d)$", "\\10\\2", x)
## [1] "MB01" "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11"  "B12"  "B13"  "B02"
```

**5) Generalization** If we don't know how many digits are involved and we want to use sufficient 0 padding to right justify them all then we can use * format in sprintf in this variation of (1).  The same approach could be used with the others. No packages are used.

```
digits <- gsub("\\D", "", x)
nondigits <- gsub("\\d", "", x)
sprintf("%s%0*d", nondigits, max(nchar(digits)), as.numeric(digits))
## [1] "MB01" "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11"  "B12"  "B13"  "B02"
```

Comment: Someone edited this to change the indentation with the result that depending on your screen some of the code may go off the end.  I have restored the version prior to that edit to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

strcapture('([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)', x, 
           proto = list(char = character(), num = numeric())) %>%
  mutate(num = str_pad(num, 2, pad = '0')) %>%
  unite(value, char, num, sep = '') %>%
  pull(value)

#[1] "MB01" "MB11" "MB12" "MB13" "B01"  "B11"  "B12"  "B13"  "B02"
```